# Laravel - Java script - Unable to load a page from web route url in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5

I'm passing a parameter in side the $ajax call to link with controller function.

**abc.blade.php**

inside onClick listener---

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{route('getFordHedGpsLocationForSelectedRep')}}",
    type: "GET",
    dataType:"json",
    data: {repc:repCode.trim()}, 
    success: function (data) 
    {
      alert("OK");
    }
});
```

---

**web.php**

```
Route::get('getFordHedGpsLocationForSelectedRep', 'MapController@getFordHedGpsLocationForSelectedRep')->name('getFordHedGpsLocationForSelectedRep');
```

**MapController.php**

```
public function getFordHedGpsLocationForSelectedRep(Request $request) 
    {
        $repCode  = $request->get("repc");

        $result = DB::select('select query to get data');

        $temp = array();
        $output = array();
        $output1 = array();

        foreach ($result as $key => $value) 
        {
            if (trim($value->RepCode) == $repCode) 
            {
                $temp['lat'] = $value->Latitude;
                $temp['lng'] = $value->Longitude;
                $temp['ref'] = $value->RefNo;
                $temp['sTime'] = $value->startTimeSO;
                $temp['eTime'] = $value->endTimeSO;
                $temp['repCode'] = $value->RepCode;
                $temp['debCode'] = $value->DebCode;
                $temp['tAmt'] = $value->TotalAmt;
                $temp['outDis'] = $value->OutDisVal;
                $temp['debName'] = $value->DebName;
                $temp['repName'] = $value->RepName;
                $temp['qty'] = $value->Qty;
                $temp['tDate'] = $value->TxnDate; 
            }                                     

            $output = isset($temp)?$temp:'';
        }

        $output1 = isset($output)?$output:'';       

        return view('selectedRepMap')->with(['repOrders'=> $output1]);

    }
```

That controller function returns a view (selectedRepMap.balde.php) with view loading data. Unfortunately page not loading automatically after the click event on abc.blade, but inspect network status got '200' for 'getFordHedGpsLocationForSelectedRep' function ($ajax call url) and double click on that function in inspect network area page loading successfully.

Comment: Its because you're using ajax. It expects json output.

Comment: When ajax request sucess, you just `alert("OK");` but process nothing, sir

Comment: @ Areg - Got it. Then I have to use ajax call without json response?

Comment: @Vo Kim Nguyen - you r correct sir...

Comment: you should use `window.location` to redirect to the page but i don't think if you can keep the `repOrders` variable

Comment: @Areg - Yep that's the point I need to resolve

Comment: i think you can replace the entire page with the view data but not redirect with data

Comment: @Areg - could you please to give me a sample code

Comment: @Areg - I changed as 'var repOrders = {repOrders: data};
                var a = JSON.stringify(repOrders);

                console.log(a);
                window.location = '/selectedRepMap' + '?' + a; '

Comment: If the `repOrders` can  be passed through `URL` you can just simply do that

Comment: $_GET['repOrders'] has {"lat":"6.114439","lng":"80.470336","ref":"OAP1911/0002","sTime":"2019-11-01 11:10:03.000","eTime":"2019-11-01 11:14:48.000","repCode":"001682 ","debCode":"RE063495 ","tAmt":"-16873.71","outDis":".00","debName":"A.K.Traders ","repName":"P.B.C. MADURANGA - COMPANY ","qty":"1471.000","tDate":"2019-11-08 00:00:00.000"} from the URL . Then how to display the 'lat', 'lng' values as <div>'lat'</div> without using javaScript. json_decode and json_decode are not supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated code**

```
public function getFordHedGpsLocationForSelectedRep(Request $request) 
{
        $repCode  = $request->get("repc");

        $result = DB::select('select query for data');

        $output1 = isset($result)?$result:'';

        return $output1;
}
```

**abc.blade.php**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{route('getFordHedGpsLocationForSelectedRep')}}",
    type: "GET",
    dataType:"json",
    data: {repc:repCode.trim()}, 
    success: function (data) 
    {
        var repOrders = {data};
        var a = JSON.stringify(data);

        console.log(a);
        window.location = '/selectedRepMap?repOrders='+ a;  
    }
  });
```

**newPage.blade.php**

```
var url_string = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var repOrders = url.searchParams.get("repOrders");
var orders = JSON.parse(repOrders);

console.log(orders['value']);
```